Definition of First Central Difference -- is this definition completely valid?
The usual definition of the "first central difference" is as follows:
Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a real function.
Let $y=f(x)$ have known values:

$y_k = f(x_k)$ for $x_k \in \{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$

defined as:

$x_k = x_0 + k h$

for some $h \in \Bbb R_{>0}$.
Then the first central difference on $f$ is defined as:

$δ_{i + 1/2} := f \left({x_i + \frac h 2}\right) − f \left({x_i - \frac h 2}\right)$

for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n − 1$.
But (and  need to understand whether it's an important "but") we are not given that we actually have the values for either $f \left({x_i + \frac h 2}\right)$ or $f \left({x_i - \frac h 2}\right)$. We are only given that we have them on the integral values of $h$.
It may be said that "clearly" it is necessary to posit the calculability (and indeed existence) of $f \left({x_i \pm \frac h 2}\right)$, which of course may not be possible if the $x_i$ are physical measurements made at fixed time intervals apart.
But in the online literature I have browsed through (yes I know, I haven't looked particularly deeply) this point is never mentioned.
Is this a trivial point that I am overthinking, or is it a valid point that needs to be stressed in any rigorous definition of the central difference operator?
Footnote: It needs perhaps to be mentioned that in David Nelson's Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics (4th ed. 2008) the definition is in fact incorrect, and the (first) central difference is in fact defined the same as the first forward difference, in both entries central difference and finite differences, so that was not much help.
It also needs to be pointed out that the definition as given in the Oxford Dictionary of Mathematics (both 5th ed 2014 and 6th ed 2021) define the first central difference on $f$ is defined as:

$δ_{i + 1/2} := \dfrac {f \left({x_{i + 1} }\right) − f \left({x_{i - 1} }\right)} 2$

for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n − 1$, which is a different (but altogether rigorous) definition.
The Collins Dictionary of Mathematics (1989) (Borowski and Borwein) do not specify a domain, merely the differences, and use a definition similar to the Oxford Dictionary of Mathematics.

I have little experience with the calculus of finite differences, but this is the first time I've seen the definition you've given. The Oxford definition at the end is the only one I've seen.

@PaulSinclair The "half h" version comes from Wikipedia. I haven't trawled through all the cited sources, but those I have accessed limit their discussions to forward diffs. I think I may just have some work to do.
